# Convert Drawable to BLOB Datatype

Tags: java, android, sqlite

```
public Drawable icon; \\ Some value in this field
```

I am creating a database in SQLite Manager. I want to store `icon` into the database. Another field is shown correctly, but when I take the `icon` field with datatype `BLOB`, it doesn't display.

```
public void prettyPrint() {
public String appname = "asd";
public String pname = "asd";
public String versionName = "asd";
public int versionCode = 0;
public Drawable icon="android.im....";
Insall_app_db i1 = new Insall_app_db();
i1.createDatabse("appInfo3", getBaseContext());
i1.createTable("off_appinfo4", getBaseContext()); i1.insertDataUser("off_appinfo4",  appid ,appname,pname, versionName, versionCode, icon, x);
}


package com.AppInfo;

import java.sql.Blob;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

import android.R.drawable;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

public class Insall_app_db {


SQLiteDatabase sampleDB = null;
String PhoneNumber;
String UserId;
Cursor c;
ArrayList ar=new ArrayList();
public void createDatabse(String DbName,Context context)
{
sampleDB =  context.openOrCreateDatabase(DbName,     
    context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE,null);

}

public void createTable(String Tablename,Context context)
{
    sampleDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
            Tablename +
            "(app_id INT,app_name VARCHAR(255),pname VARCHAR(255),version_name  VARCHAR(25),versionCode  INT,icon BLOB,date DATE);");

}
public void DeleteTable(String Tablename,Context context)
{
    sampleDB.execSQL("DROP TABLE off_appinfo4");

}

public void insertDataUser(String tableName,int app_id,String app_name,String pname,String version_name,int versionCode,String d,long date1)
{

     sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
             tableName +
             " Values ("+app_id+",'"+app_name+"','"+pname+"','"+version_name+"','"+versionCode+"','"+d+"',"+date1+");");


}

public String GetUserData(Context context,String tablename)
{
            c = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT User_Id FROM " +
                tablename +
                "", null);

            if(c!=null)
            {
                if(c.moveToFirst())
                {
                    do
                    {
                        UserId=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("User_Id"));

                    }while(c.moveToNext());



                    }   

                }       

            return UserId;
}

public void close()
{
    sampleDB.close();

}




}
```

Comment: how you are doing code please?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can convert your image into byte array and store that bytearray in blob filed in database. You can retrieve your image back from database as byte array.

### How to get byte array from imageview:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splashImageView);
Drawable d = iv.getBackground();
BitmapDrawable bitDw = ((BitmapDrawable) d);
Bitmap bitmap = bitDw.getBitmap();
System.out.println(".....d....."+d);
System.out.println("...bitDw...."+bitDw);
System.out.println("....bitmap...."+bitmap);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
byte[] imageInByte = stream.toByteArray();
```

### Store byte array in database:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put(CHUNK, buffer); //CHUNK blob type field of your table
long rawId = database.insert(TABLE, null, cv); //TABLE table name
```

### Retrieve image from byte array:

```
public static Bitmap convertByteArrayToBitmap(
    byte[] byteArrayToBeCOnvertedIntoBitMap)
{
    bitMapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
        byteArrayToBeCOnvertedIntoBitMap, 0,
        byteArrayToBeCOnvertedIntoBitMap.length);
    return bitMapImage;
}
```

Comment: can you give example of  Convert Drawable to BLOB Datatype sqlite and Convert BLOB to Drawable .

Comment: whether the approach tha I have described worked for u or not?

Comment: no its not, and i am confuse about it that how can i do this?

Comment: what is the problem you got in that approach?

Comment: values are in  
byte[] imageInByte = stream.toByteArray();
i just set BLOB datatype in DB,so how can i initialize ?
and how can i get back and convert it to bitmapImage? or Drawable

Comment: refer thid [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384439/convert-drawable-to-blob-datatype-sqlite-problem]

Comment: can you tell me that what is buffer?
ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        cv.put(CHUNK, buffer);       //CHUNK blob type field of your table
        long rawId=database.insert(TABLE, null, cv);

Answer (score 0):

I made few changes in above answer to get byte array imageview

ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splashImageView);

```
iv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = iv.getDrawingCache();
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        byte[] bitmapdata = stream.toByteArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to save multiple images to database then you can create own method as following :
//retrieve images from drawable into int array:

```
int[] IMAGES = { R.drawable.yourimage1, R.drawable.yourimage2, R.drawable.yourimage3,
            R.drawable.yourimage4, R.drawable.yourimage5 }; 

//create method to convert drawable images(which are in int) to byte[] as below:

public byte[] convertToByteArray(int image){

        Resources resources = getResources();
        Drawable drawable = resources.getDrawable(image);
        Bitmap bitmap =  ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress( Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        byte[] bitmapData = stream.toByteArray();

              return bitmapData;

    }
```

and now call this method as below:
               byte [] image = convertToByteArray(IMAGES[position]);//
               dbAdapter.insertValues(image);