# Convert Drawable to BLOB Datatype sqlite problem

Tags: android, google-maps

Here I am attaching code in which store image in Drawable and pass to Database with BLOB Datatype.

I try this, it store properly but not display image.

```
Insall_app_db i1 = new Insall_app_db();
i1.createDatabse(DB, getBaseContext());
i1.createTable(tableName, getBaseContext());

BitmapDrawable bitDw = ((BitmapDrawable) icon);
Bitmap bitmap = bitDw.getBitmap();
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
byte[] imageInByte = stream.toByteArray();
String iconStr = imageInByte.toString();
i1.insertDataUser(tableName,appid,appname2,pname, versionName, versionCode,iconStr, long_date);
int appid = i1.GetUserData(getBaseContext(), tableName);

System.out.println("-------------------------------");
byte[] imaaa = iconStr.getBytes();

Bitmap aaa = convertByteArrayToBitmap(imaaa);

LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
v = li.inflate(R.layout.icon,null);
TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.icon_text);
tv.setText(i1.app_name);
ImageView iv = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.icon_image);
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
Bitmap bitmap2 = ((BitmapDrawable)icon).getBitmap();
iv.setImageBitmap(aaa);
```

Is there any other solution to do this thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the image from the sqlite database i used the following:

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 byte[] data=cur.getBlob(cur.getColumnIndex("img"));
 baos.write(data);
```

Then to display the image i used to do the following:

```
 InputStream is = database.getImageStream(someId);
 Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
```

The code below shows how to save the image into a BLOB field

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();      
image.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos); 
byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
```

the bytes can be added to sqlite using

```
 initialValues.put("<fieldname>", bytes); //ofcourse <fieldname> is of type BLOB
```

Comment: how to store baos in Database with BLOB datatype?

Comment: Drawable icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager()); 
Blob b; how can i store icon into Blob?

Comment: ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 

this.image.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);

byte[] bytes =  bos.toByteArray(); 

the bytes can be added to sqlite using

initialValues.put("<fieldname>", bytes); //ofcourse <fieldname> is of type BLOB