# Simple Voice Command in Android

Tags: android, speech-recognition, voice, audio

So got a project to make an application for blind people and decided to make it in android.
The application is really simple, maybe something like this:

```
1. User press the button and say a word (ex: Ja - Pan)
2. The program search in database and find a data labeled Japan
3. The program plays the data that had been searched
   the data in here is basically an audio
```

I heard that android already has it's own Speech recognition but it need to be online

```
1. is there any way to make it offline and read my database not google database ?
2. if not, are there any source code about speech recognition so i can learn from it?
3. how to input sound in database? so far i only know how to input text in SQLight
```

I really need a help in here
btw I'm from indonesia....nice to meet you all :D

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17674655

Comment: Check [Pocketsphinx on android](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid), it has few advantages over google: ability to activate search by voice, no need to press keyboard button, ability to specify the list of words to search for, offline function. As for storing sound in a database, there is no need in that, you can just store the files in filesystem. Though storage of binary data in database is also perfectly possible. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9395755/error-while-inserting-blob-data-into-sqlite-on-android

Answer (score 0):

Here are the few answers to your question.

> 1. is there any way to make it offline and read my database not google database ?

Yes it is possible , you can make use of sphinks for the detail you can check [here](http://1.%20is%20there%20any%20way%20to%20make%20it%20offline%20and%20read%20my%20database%20not%20google%20database%20?)

2

> how to input sound in database? so far i only know how to input text 
>   in SQLight

You have to convert the speech to text again you can make use of Sphinx.Then you can store that text in database